# file:// urls and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications

I have an intranet application, which for many years has made use of the file:// syntax for urls to link to resources on (hopefully) network shares. I know that uploading instead of linking, and perhaps using webDAV would be a better solution, but that is currently outside of the scope of my problem.

Until very recently, accessing a file:// link from a page worked fine. However, recently it has stopped working. I can finds references to mozilla preventing file:// links from working when accessed from an http:// or https:// page, but I cannot find any reference to Internet Explorer implementing the same behaviour.
I am assuming a windows update has done this, because even IE6 has started to exhibit this behaviour, and I know for sure that IE6 and IE7 have been working fine.
Unfortunately I cannot be sure exactly when it stopped working.

Someone else must have come across this and can give me a definitive answer as to whether this potential security hole has been 'fixed'.

ALl info greatly appreciated

Comment: you could try to change security settings for IE (zones, truested sites etc.?) if that helps somehow?

Comment: Could be a system hotpatch changed IE's behavior. Would you find better help posting this to superuser.com or serverfault?

Comment: I've been through all the security settings (IE6), and none are related. The site was already in the Intranet zone, but I've tried various options with zones, and as expected, didn't make any difference.
I may try serverfault - it's a borderline case - but as it may be hotfix related, it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your site to "Trusted sites", as explained here:

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/ie/elevlocalfile.htm

> The issue is a new security feature in
>   Internet Explore 6 Service Pack 1. In
>   order to prevent Internet vicious
>   codes from accessing your local files,
>   the development team developed the new
>   security feature and included it in
>   IE6 SP1. Please be advised that this
>   is a normal behavior. Actually, IE6
>   SP1 includes new security code checks
>   that prevent "zone elevation". This
>   means that documents located in the
>   "Internet" zone will not be granted
>   access (through HREFs,
>   scripting...etc) to documents in the
>   "My Computer" zone

...

> In Windows XP Service Pack 2, no site
>   from any Zone can open files in local
>   machine zone, whereas in pre-SP2, only
>   Internet Zone sites were restricted to
>   open local files, while
>   Trusted/Intranet can.

Comment: Very useful info. Thanks
Further testing has shown that IE6 won't obey any of the Intranet/Internet zones rules, and refuses all file:// links unless you use one the registry hacks mentions in the mvps post, above. IE8 doesn't care about the zones. IE7 testing in progress.

Comment: I can also confirm that at east of the problem is due to user error. Some links that I thought were valid actually weren't. I was expecting a 'Not found' popup, but this doesn't appear in IE6. The only surefire way to tell if a link is valid is to Right-click, Save Target As. No save dialog means a broken link.